# Importing item from sd card and tabview is being used

Tags: android, android-listview, android-image, android-tabactivity, android-music-player

I want to create a project where I've two tabs(SONGS and IMAGES)
If I click on SONGS tab, I want the entire list of songs stored in my sd card or internal storage. Similarly, when I go to the Images tab, all the images are visible to me. 
Also on click on the music file its should start playing music and on clicking the image, it should display the image.can someone please provide me with the entire code?
your help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To find all the audio files on SD card, create a method like this

```
private void findAllMusicFiles()
{       
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DATA, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor audioCursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

    if (audioCursor != null) {
        while (audioCursor.moveToNext()) {

            mediaNameList.add(audioCursor.getString(audioCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));
            mediaPathList.add(audioCursor.getString(0));

        }
        audioCursor.close();
    }
}
```

mediaNameList contains only the names of files to display

mediaPathList contains path to those files

both these are array lists

pass these list to an adapter and call onItemClickListener to get the path of the file (by position) that you want to play

to play selected song using media player, you may try the following (this part is still under development, so you might get some issues)

```
songList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Toast.makeText(mContext, mediaNameList.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            try {
                if(player.isPlaying()){
                    player.stop();
                    player.release();
                    player=null;
                }else{
                    player.reset();
                    player.setDataSource(mediaPathList.get(position));
                    player.prepare();
                    player.start();
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }           

        }
    });
}
```

click song name once to start playing, click 2nd time to stop

Comment: Thanku but i think you didn't get my question.

Comment: With reference to your first code, do i have to make any XML file or edir my main XML file??

Comment: yes you will have to make xml for how your list of song names will look like and use this xml in your adapter. The two array list that i gave you mediaNameList and mediaPathList will work as data for that song list. Similarly you can prepare your images list too. What i gave you is just to give an idea for search logic through whole SD card and logic to play and stop audio file.

Comment: Thanks mate. Will be troubling you a little more with my queries in future.
thanks again..:)